# Send an object with it's parent class through express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering if there is any way in which I can send an object from an express server, and then check the `instanceof` that object on the receiving end.

I'm writing integration tests for express, and want to check the `instanceof` of the response body. Sadly, the prototype is lost (my guess is that it's lost due to `stringify` and `parse`).

To clarify:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

class ParentClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
};

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name),
    this.age = age;
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let myChild = new ChildClass('test', 21)
  res.json(myChild)
});

server = app.listen('3005', '0.0.0.0');

request.get(`http://localhost:3005`, (err, response, body) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body) instanceof ParentClass)
})
```

The `body` that gets printed is:

```
name: 'test',
age: 21,
__proto__: Object
```

My final goal is that the line `body instanceof ParentClass` will return **true**, but currently it returns **false**.

Comment: I think you're correct that the instance is lost as your object is being converted to JSON. What happens if you use `res.bodymyChild)` instead?

Also, checking the instance of in an integration test seems a bit redundant. As far as an end user is concerned, they don't care if the object comes from child or parent class. Can't you just check the value has a name property? Wouldn't this would infer that it has inherited properties from the parent.

Comment: This: _My final goal is that the line body instanceof ParentClass will return true, but currently it returns false._ will always be the case when using `JSON.parse()` regardless of the environment. `JSON.parse()` has no way to infer the object type, so it will aways create generic Object objects. You can verify this by checking the `.constructor` property of the `JSON.parse()` output.

Comment: There are two ways to write your tests. 1) Assert that each property exists individually OR 2) Construct a new object of the expected type and use `Object.assign()`, then assert a match to a  test object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP request is returning a string, in this case the stringified versions of your object. This won't hold any data about the classes of the javascript, so you won't be able to use `instanceof` on the receiving end because it's just a string.

One thing you might be able to do is add a property to your base class that compiles its prototype chain into an array, then you can simple check if the class name you are looking for is in that array.

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // build class chain
    this.classes = []
    let p = Object.getPrototypeOf(this)
    while (p) {
      this.classes.push(p.constructor.name)
      p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p)
    }
  }
};

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(name, age) {
    super(name)
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let myChild = new ChildClass('test', 21)
// has classes property that will be stringified
let childString = JSON.stringify(myChild)
console.log(childString)

// on the client side
let obj = JSON.parse(childString)
console.log("Instance of Parent?", obj.classes.includes('ParentClass')) // instaed of instanceof
```

Really not sure if this will work for your use case…it seems like a strange thing to test for. It might be better to test actual behavior rather than specific implementation.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! The reason I am checking implementation is that the parent class itself gives me alot of info about the object, without having to assert 5 different things.